# open and get exact size of existing memory mapped file on windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, memory-mapped-files

There is one of our service log file which mapped to memory. I have another application tracing some regex on log file, so I need to get log file size periodically and read coming lines if any.  I check log file size by ftell() to get size in bytes however it returns 4mb since it is mapped to 4mb are I guess.

I can either use C or C++. My logic simply like below:

```
FILE *f = fopen("logfile.log", "r")
// go to file end to get current end position
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END)
// ftell() always returns 4mb when actual file size is less than 4mb
// I need to get exact size of log file
currentEnd = ftell(f)
// go last read position
fseek(f, previousEnd, SEEK_SET)
//read from previousEnd to currentEnd with fread
// update last read position
previousEnd = currentEnd
```

Is there a way to get exact size of existing mapped files in bytes on windows?
   Any suggestion and idea appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What does GetFileSizeEx() say?

Comment: Hi Medinoc, unfourtunately result is 4mb again, it does not say exact current real size too.

Comment: Is the file supposed to be bigger or smaller than 4mb? If the latter, I have little hope (if it's mapped to 4mb, then it's considered at least 4mb long). If the former, I have little hope either because GetFileSizeEx etc. *should* work...

Comment: It starts with 4mb size even it has one line and after a while, with coming lines it exceeds 4mb. So I can say that it is considered at least 4mb long.

Comment: I don't think you're using the term "memory mapped file" correctly. This does not look like a memory mapped file at all, it looks like a regular file with the name `logfile.log`. You are opening it with the bog-standard `fopen` function. A memory mapped file is not simply one that you've opened for I/O.

Comment: Your log may be using buffered I/O so you won't see updates straight away...

Comment: Hi Len, I don't think it is buffered I/O because when I open service log file with any file editor I can see new lines immediately.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way, because you're wrong. As soon as you map 4mb of file, the system will resize the file to 4mb. That's easy to check:

```
HANDLE file = CreateFile(_T("1.txt"), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, 0);
HANDLE mapping = CreateFileMapping(file, 0, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 4*1024*1024, 0);
void* view = MapViewOfFile(mapping, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);
```

Run this code and close the program (cleanup omitted for clarity). You will see the file is 4mb now. Clearly, there's no way you can get any sort of 'position' since there isn't any.

I believe the root of the problem is your desire to map the log file in the first place. Not only you run into problems with position, you also have another problem when the log size exceeds 4mb. Why didn't you just write to log file as usual?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Let me make it clear again. We have third-party service and I want to trade its log file for some of keywords. I want to periodically check file size and if there is any updates then seek to last read position and read new lines. But I get 4mb file size whenever I call ftell(f, 0, SEEK_END).

Comment: Open the log in notepad and see whats its length is. Also, clarify what you mean by 'memory mapped file'

Comment: when I open with notepad it has too much spaces at the end of the file. It is not a regular file, when I periodically try to read with fread(), it seems buffering output after a while it write to file. Thanks.

Comment: I believe these "spaces" add up to 4mb. So the file size is 4mb. I'm still not sure what you mean by "memory mapped file".

Comment: If file has logs smaller than size of 4mb, then other part of file is filled with null character. So that file size is initially 4mb and it increases 4mb when file filled valid logs. I do not know why service fills remain part of file like that but I can tail log lines by manipulating file position. When I read I also check length of buffer which returns 0 if I read null character chunk. In this case I return back to last position of file before read etc. Thanks for your all time and conisderations.